# Infinite recursion ! how to convert?

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist, infinite-loop, converters

I have following classes

```
class SomeClass{

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private List<SomeClass> history;

}
```

```
class SomeClassDto{

    private String name;
    private List<SomeClassDto> historyDto;
}
```

Now i want a method to convert this **SomeClass** Object to **SomeClassDto**.

Comment: What is with this title?

Comment: The only ways you could get infinite recursion doing that, is: 1) You wrote bad code, but since you haven't shown any code, we can't help with that. --- 2) A `SomeClass` object somehow contains itself in its `history` (directly or nested), which doesn't seem right, so that would be a data corruption, so you should try to fix that, instead of changing this code.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a constructor in `SomeClassDTO` which takes `SomeClass` as a parameter and then do the conversion:

```
class SomeClassDto{

    private String name;
    private List<SomeClassDto> historyDto;

    public SomeClassDto(SomeClass someClass){
        this.name = someClass.getName();
        this.historyDto = new ArrayList<>();
        for(SomeClass sc: someClass.getHistory()){
            this.historyDto.add(new SomeClassDto(sc));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what about history of history?

Comment: it will be taken care of automatically in the loops

Comment: if the **same** instance is in distinct histories, this will create a new instance for each instead of just one (and for sure will create infinite recursion if one instance contains itself in its history (maybe an invalid state, but who knows))

Answer (score 0):

You should use cache for objects:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

/**
 * Created by aprisadkov on 18.02.2020.
 */
public class InfiniteConvert {
    class SomeClass{

        private String id;
        private String name;
        private List<SomeClass> history;

    }
    class someClassDto{

        private String name;
        private List<someClassDto> historyDto;
    }
    HashMap<String, someClassDto> objById = new HashMap();

    public someClassDto convertDto(SomeClass someObj)
    {
        someClassDto ret = objById.get(someObj.id);

        if(ret == null) {
            ret = new someClassDto();
            objById.put(someObj.id, ret);

            ret.name = someObj.name;
            ret.historyDto = someObj.history.stream().map(t -> convertDto(t)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
        return ret;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        InfiniteConvert m = new InfiniteConvert();
        m.test();
    }

    public void test()
    {
        SomeClass s1 = new SomeClass();
        s1.id = "1";
        s1.name = "s1";
        SomeClass s2 = new SomeClass();
        s2.id = "2";
        s2.name = "s2";
        SomeClass s3 = new SomeClass();
        s3.id = "3";
        s3.name = "s3";
        SomeClass s4 = new SomeClass();
        s4.id = "4";
        s4.name = "s4";

        s1.history = Arrays.asList(s2,s3,s4);
        s2.history = Arrays.asList(s3,s4);
        s3.history = Arrays.asList(s4);
        s4.history = Arrays.asList(s2,s3,s1);
        someClassDto sn =  convertDto(s1);
    }
}
```